# TCP/Telnet connection Winform to Winform c#

Tags: c#, sockets, simulation, telnet

I wish to simulate a connection between two forms in an application (it's a telephone network simulator).

I want to go beyond using simple methods to pretend there is a connection (IsEngaged(), IsConnected()) and somehow create an actual connection between the forms (telephones).

Am I correct in thinking I should be able to do this via telnet/tcp?

I'm not asking for a complete solution but would appreciate a nod in the right direction. All of my searches so far have come up with nothing similar to my scenario.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with telnet - implementing Telnet is rather "hard work"...

For simulation purposes you can mock this with TCP or UDP or named pipe - anything usable for (bidirectional) IPC should work...